# How do I get the camera view to work in ngx-scanner?

Tags: angular, typescript, zxing-js

I'm making an app that makes use of a QR code scanner.  I'm using the ngx-scanner component which is a ported version of Google's ZXing scanning library for Angular.
The problem:
Everytime I'm using the scanner component I get no errors but the camera view for the scanner won't load and I will just get the same screen I have as a background in my app.

Here's my HTML and my TS export class

```
<zxing-scanner [enable]="scannerEnabled" (scanSuccess)="onScanSuccess($event)"></zxing-scanner>
<h1><strong> {{ result }} </strong></h1>
```

```
export class QrScannerComponent implements OnInit {
  scannerEnabled = true;
  result: string

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onScanSuccess(result: string) {
    this.result = result
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, have you tried to log the scan failure even from that component?

At the template, define the formats to read, in my case, I only want to read QR Codes or EAN as well.

```html
<zxing-scanner
  #scanner
  [formats]="['QR_CODE', 'EAN_13']"
  (camerasFound)="cameraFound($event)"
  (camerasNotFound)="camerasNotFound($event)"
  (scanSuccess)="scanSuccessHandler($event)"
>
</zxing-scanner>
```

At the component:

```
  camerasNotFound(e: Event) {
    // Display an alert modal here
  }

  cameraFound(e: Event) {
    // Log to see if the camera was found
  }

  onScanSuccess(result: string) {
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Which version are you using by the way?

**EDIT**

```
:host zxing-scanner ::ng-deep video{
  height: 15rem;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: contain;
}

video {
  height: 15rem !important;
}
```

Comment: I just applied the changes you told me and they all work fine.  In my PC ( where I have no camera) there's a "no camera found" text being created and in my Phone there's a "camera found" text.
I also want to mention that the messages on both devices show up after I refresh the page.

Could it be something CSS related? Here's a link to the project if it helps 
https://fieldid-907bc.web.app/qrScanner

Comment: I have added a scss code which I am using at some project with this library, maybe that could be the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the library is supposed to make a camera view appear no matter what ind of SCSS I'm using.  So it's unlikely that that's my problem.  I will wait for the people who made the library to do some updates.  Thank you very much for your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue as well, looks like the only way I've been able to solve it is by choosing a device after the scanner has been initiated.